# How to systematically update a parent category in CoreData using User input?

Tags: swift, core-data, parent-child

I am new to coding and core data. I have an entity called "Games" that has 2 attributes "title"(String) and "saved" (Bool). Games is the parent category to the entity "Player" that has one attribute "playerName"(String). I want the app to update the title and saved attributes for all Players with the Game title "New Game" based on their input when they press the save game button. I want the attributes to be updated without knowing the exact amount of players that will be in the tableview.

`import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var playerNames: UITableView!

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

var playerArray = [Player]()
var savedGames = [Games]()

var selectedGameName : Games?

var newGameName = "Test"
let savedGame = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    playerNames.dataSource = self
    
    let newGame1 = Games(context: context)
    newGame1.title = "New Game"
    newGame1.saved = false
    savedGames.append(newGame1)
    
    selectedGameName = newGame1
    
    saveItems()
    
    let newPlayer1 = Player(context: context)
    newPlayer1.playerName = "Player 1"
    newPlayer1.parentCategory = selectedGameName
    newPlayer1.title = selectedGameName?.title!
    newPlayer1.saved = selectedGameName!.saved
    playerArray.append(newPlayer1)
    
    saveItems()
    loadPlayers()
    self.playerNames.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var textField = UITextField()
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Player", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Player", style: .default){ [self](action) in
        //what happens once the user clicks the add player button
        let newPlayer = Player(context: context)
        newPlayer.playerName = textField.text!
        newPlayer.parentCategory = selectedGameName
        newPlayer.title = selectedGameName?.title!
        newPlayer.saved = selectedGameName!.saved
        playerArray.append(newPlayer)
        
        saveItems()
        
        self.playerNames.reloadData()
        
    }
    
    alert.addTextField { playerTextField in
        playerTextField.placeholder = "Player Name"
        textField = playerTextField
    }
    
    alert.addAction(action)
    
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func savedGamePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var textField = UITextField()
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Name This Game", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Save Game", style: .default){ [self](action) in
        //what happens once the user clicks the saved game button
        newGameName = textField.text!
        
        let newGameName = selectedGameName
        //How do I change all players in tableview to have Game name of newGameName and a saved of savedGame?
        
    }
    
    alert.addTextField { playerTextField in
        playerTextField.placeholder = "Game Name"
        textField = playerTextField
    }
    
    alert.addAction(action)
    
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}

func saveItems(){
    
    do{
        try context.save()
    }catch{
        print("Error saving")
    }
    
    playerNames.reloadData()
}

func loadPlayers(){
    let request : NSFetchRequest<Player> = Player.fetchRequest()
    do{
       playerArray = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch{
        print("Error fetching")
    }
    playerNames.reloadData()
}
```

}

//MARK: - Tableview functions

//Shows the data on the tableview
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource{

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return playerArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = playerArray[indexPath.row].playerName
    
    return cell
}
```

}`

I'm not really sure what to even try here. I tried a couple of variation of appending the data but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things so much more complicated for yourself by duplicating data and trying to keep it up to date. I would remove the two duplicate attributes from Player and instead access them via the Game relationship. For example

```
playerArray[indexPath.row].parentCategory.title
```

This way all rows in your table view will be correctly updated if you change the `title` attribute of the `Game` object

Comment: Sorry I'm not following. I can't save the new player if I don't have the title and saved attributes since they are mandatory in the Games entity. If I call the parentCategory.title in the CellForRowAt I only see the title of the game in the tableView not the playerNames.

Comment: The players name is a different attribute that you need to add as well to the function, this was only meant as an example how to access the title from Game rather than using a duplicate.